# use xpath contains ignoring accents

Tags: xml, xpath, diacritics

I have the following xml:

```
<p id="korlatozas" class="korlatozas">Akácos u.; Alkony u.; Alkotmány u.; Állomás u.; Almássy K. tér; Alpár u.; Alsósor u.; Arany J. u.; Árpád u.; Árpád u.; Árvíz u.; Attila u.; Aulich L. u.; Babits u.; Bajcsy-Zsilinszki u. Bánya u.; Bástya u.; Báthory u.; Batthyány u.; Bay tér; Béke sgt páros oldal; Béke tér; Béke u.; Bethlen G. u.; Bibic u.; Bihari u.; Bocskai u.; Botond u.; Böki út; Corvin u.; Csendes u.; Csiga u.; Csókos u.; Damjanich u.; Dancza u.; Darvas J. u.; Deák F. tér; Délibáb u.; Derkovics köz; Diófa u.; Dob u.; Dózsa Gy.u.; Ecsedi u.; Eminescu u.; Erdélyi S. u.; Erdős K. köz; Erkel tér; Ernyő u.; Erzsébet u.; Esze T. u.; Eszperantó tér; Farkashalom tanya; Fehér-Körös u.; Fekete sas u.; Furminc u.; Gábor Á. u.; Galamb u.; Gallacz J. u.; Gelvács u.; Garay u.; Görbe u.; Gát u.; Gyár u; Gyöngyösi u.; Gyöngyvirág tér; Gyulai László u; Hajnal; u.; Hajós u.; Halász Sor.; Harrucken tér; Határőr u.; Hársfa u.; Hét vezér u.; Híd u.; Hold u.; Hollósy köz; Horgász u.; Horváth F. u.; Hunyadi u.; Huszka u.; Illyés Gy. u.; Irinyi J. u.; Iskola u.; József A. tér; József A. u.; Juhász Gy. u.; József Benedek tanya; Kaffka M. u.; Kálvária tanya; Kálvin, u.; Kapa u.; Karácsony J. u.; Károlyi M. u.; Kastélykert u.; Katona J. tér; Kazinczy u.; Kenyérsütő u.; Kerecsényi u.; Kerék u.; Kertalj u.; Kertes u.; Keszi u.; Kétegyházi út; Kétmalom u.; Kígyó u.; Kígyósi u.; Kinizsi P. u.; Kisbök u.; Kiss J. u.; Kisvasút u.; Klapka Gy u.; Kodály Z. u.; Kohán Gy. u.; Kossuth L. u.; Kökény u.; Körgát u.; Kölcsey u.; Kölcsey u.; Körösi Cs. S. u.; Kurta u.; Kurucz u.; Kürt u.; Laktanya u.; Lehel u.; Liceum tér; Liget u.; Madarász köz; Malom u.; Madách u.; Malomsor u.; Mályvádi u.; Maróthi u.; Mátyás kir u.; Megyeház u.; Mikes K. u.; Mikszáth K. u.; Móra F .u.; Móricz Zs. u.; Munkácsy M. u.; Nagybök u.; Nagyváradi út; Oláh Gy. u.; Pacsirta u.; Pálffy u.; Part u.; Petőfi tér; Petőfi u.; Pejrét tanya; Pfiffner P. u.;Pomucz tábornok tér; Pomucz u.; Rábai M. u.; Radnóti u.; Rajki L. u.; Régi temető u.; Réthy L. u.; Réz J. u; Rövid u.; Sánc u.; Sarkadi út; Sándorhegy tanya; Sáros u.; Semmelweis u.; Seregélyes dűlő; Simonyi tér; Sinka I. u.; Síp u.; Sirály u.; Sittye u.; Sólymos u.; Sólyom u.; Sport u.; Szabó P. u.; Szabadka u.; Szakáll L. u.; Szarvas u.; Széchenyi tér; Széchenyi u.; Szegedi Kiss I. u; Szélső u.; Szlányi tanya; Szent István u.; Szent L. u.; Szép u.; Szilva u.; Szinyei köz; Szív u.; Szőlőskert u.; Szőnyi köz; Tábor u.; Táncsics u.; Tavasz u.; Temesvári út; Terényi u.; Thorma köz; Thököly u.; Tiborc u.; Toldi u.; Toldi köz; Tomcsányi u.; Tompa u.; Tornyai köz; Toronyi u.; Tölgyfa u.; Uhrin J.u.; Új élet u.; Újsor u.; Újülés u.; Vadaskert u.; Vajda u.; Vár u.; Váralja tér; Várfürdő u.; Várkert u.; Városház u.; Vasút u.; Veress E. u.; Vértes u.; Villa u.; Wesselényi u.; Zöldfa u.; Zrínyi u.; Zug u.; Zsák u.; Zsinór u.; 48-as u.;</p>
```

And another one

```
<p id="korlatozas" class="korlatozas">Ady E. u.; Ajtóssy A. u.; Álmos vezér tér; Apor V. tér; Aranyág dűlő; Aranyág u.; Árnyas u.; Asztalos J. u.; Bacsó B. u.; Bajza u.; Balassa u.; Balázs deák u.; Bárány u.; Bárdos u.; Baross u.; Bársony u.; Bartók B. u.; Béke sgt. páratlan oldal; Bem J. u.; Bajnok u.; Bem J. tér; Bercsényi u.; Belső-Törökzug tanya; Berzsenyi u.; Blanár L. u.; Bodoky u.; Bodorka u.; Bodza u.; Bogáncs u.; Bicere tanya; Borz u.; Brassói u.; Budai Nagy A. u.; Budapest krt; Budrió Itp.; Bulcsu u.; Búzavirág u.; Cinka P. u.; Csabai út; Csatorna u.; Cselebi u.; Cserjés u.; Csikóséri sor; Csokonai u.; Dobay u.; Dobó u.; Dobos I. u.; Dobozi út; Dombi L. u.; Dr. Adler I. u.; Dürer A. u.; Első u.; Eötvös L. u.; Erdő tér; Epreskert u.; Észak-Törökzug ; Faiskola u.; Fecske u.; Ferencesek tere; Ferenczy B. u.; Fő u.; Földvári u.; Fürj u.; Gárdonyi G. u.; Gólyahír; Göndöcs u.; Gyep u.; Gyóni G.u.; Gyulai Gál Albert u. Halácsy u.; Határ u.; Henyei M. u.; Hódi u.; Holdas u.; Honvéd u.; Honvéd Itp.; Hosszú u.; Ibolya u.; Ilosvai u.; Ince pápa u.; Jász Lukács u.; Jókai M. u.; József Dezső u.; Kárpát u.; Kassai u.; Kamilla u.; Kertész u.; Késmárki u.; Kis u.;Kisökörjárás tanya; Kiss E. u.; Knézich u.; Kolozsvári u.; Komáromi u.; Kossuth Lajos tér; Kosztolányi u.; Kosár u.; Kőműves u.; Köröspart u.; K. Schriffert J.u.; Kulcs u.; Kulacs u.; Külső-Törökzug tanya; Lahner Gy u.; Láncház u.; Leiningen u.; Lenkei u.;Lila akác u.; Liliom köz; Liszt F. u.; Mágocsi u.; Mágocsi köz; Mogyoróssy u.; N. Szabados u.; Nagysándor J u.; Nagyfenék tanya; Nagyökörjárás tanya; Nap u.; Nürnbergi u.; Nuszbek u.; Október 6 tér; Orgona sétány; Orsovai u.; Palló u.; Pap u.; Patócsy u.; Petik A. u.; Pikó gát sor; Pipacs u.; Pitypang u.; Pósteleki u.; Pozsonyi u.; Rákóczi F. u.; Remete tanya; Rosu u.; Rulikowszki u.; Scherer Ferenc u.; Selyem u.; Sikló sor; Sin sor; Somogyi B. u.; Siórét tanya; Siórét u.; Sitka tanya; Stéberl A. u.; Szabadkai u.; Szarkaláb u.; Szegfű u.; Székely A. u.; Szeregyháza tanya; Szentháromság u.; Szt.József u.; Szerecsen u.; Szigligeti u.; Szikfű u.; Szőlős u.; Szüret u.; T. u.; Temesvári u.; Temető u.; Tessedik S. u.; Tinódi u.; Tormássy tér; Török Ignác u.; Törökzugi ltp.; Törökzugi sor; Tulipán köz;Vadvirág; Varsándi u.; Vásár u.; Vásárhelyi P. u.; Vasvári P. u.; Vécsey K.u.; Vértanuk u.; Virág u.; Vizi u.; Vörösmarty u.; Zöldi u.; Zrínyi M tér; Bodoky major;</p>
```

I want to find the sibling element ( I can manage it ) but my problem is I want to find that p where it contains my data.
I tried this one :

```
contains(//p[@id="korlatozas"],"Almos")
```

as you can see I want to search **Almos**, but in the xml there is **Álmos** with accent.
Is it possible to find the [//p] this way?

Comment: Is this XPath 1.0 or 2.0? In XPath 2.0 you can specify a collation to be used for the string comparison: though the availability of a suitable collation depends on your XPath processor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with the translate function.

```
contains(translate(//p[@id="korlatozas"],"Ááéó","Aaeo"),"Almos")
```

Obviously, add in any other foreign characters you need to. This converts all of the characters in the second string that are found in the first, by replacing them with the corresponding character in the third. It's very similar to a common technique used for doing upper/lower case, using a translate from 'ABC' to 'abc' etc.

Comment: +1 Perhaps you could add that this now finds both `Álmos` _and_ `Almos`, if both exist in the input.

Comment: True, but I assumed that was required- if it wasn't then simply searching for `Álmos` on it's own would have been sufficient.

Comment: Yes, that's the required behaviour. I meant to suggest an additional explanation of what happens to the string. It does not actually ignore diacritics, rather it normalizes several surface forms to a common token.

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but it doesnt work do you have any idiea why.
here is the prinktscree:
http://kepfeltoltes.hu/140918/false_xpath_www.kepfeltoltes.hu_.png
 * I couldnt test in in the selenium it may work there but I can only test it there tomorrow.

Comment: Two possibilities- your `//[@id="korlatozas"]` isn't matching the node you think it is (which should be unlikely, it's an ID)- try putting just that into the xpath checker and see if you get what you expect. Or there's some sort of issue handling the special characters. Try searching the text for just `lmos` instead- if it doesn't find that, then it's nothing to do with the special characters.

Answer (score 2):

If your processor supports [XPath Full Text](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-full-text-10), you can also use

```
//p[@id="korlatozas"] contains text "Almos" using diacritics insensitive
```

This is quote nice in my opinion, because it is very clear and explicit in what you are doing. Of course, if Full Text is not supported, you can still use @Flynn1179's answer.